# Infinite for loop? ()in c

Tags: c, for-loop

the value of i resets after it reachers 7

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){

    char marks[10];
    int i;

    printf("enter the numbers:\n");
    printf("-------------------\n");
    
    for (i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",i);
        printf("element %d-",i);
        scanf("%d", &marks[i]);
    }

    printf("\n all %d",marks);
    printf("\n second %d\n",marks[1]);
return 0;
}
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1ZUz.png)

Comment: Please don't show images of text. Copy&paste the output to your question *as text*  and format it as a separate code block. To do this you can [edit] your question. Please also show the input.

Comment: `scanf("%d", &marks[i]);` invokes *undefined behavior*  because you tell `scanf` to expect a `int*` but are passing a `char*` instead

Comment: Didn't your compiler issue any warnings?

Comment: You are trying to read an `int` into a `char` variable, which is undefined behavior. You also print `marks` with `%d`, which would print only its address (or some portion of it, anyway) in some unusable form, but not the content.

Comment: What do you expect `printf("\n all %d",marks);` to do? Format specifier `%d` expects a value of type `int`, but you pass a `char` array which is a pointer to the first array element.

Comment: We really need a canonical dupe for "wrong format specifier" questions. For now I close vote them as simple typo.

Comment: Akshat Sharma, save time.  Enable all compiler warnings.

Comment: `scanf("%d", &marks[i]);` --> `scanf("%hhd", &marks[i]);`

Answer (score 2):

Problem is here:

```
scanf("%d", &marks[i]);
```

Specifier `"%d"` expects a pointer to `int`, not `char`. Usually it will write 4 bytes what is a typical size of `int`.
Therefore on 8th iteration the elements of `marks` at index from 7 to 10 are touched. However, `marks[10]` is outside of `marks` array (only indices 0-9) are valid. Undefined Behaviour is invoked and the program can do anything, from crashing to infinite looping or conjuring nasal deamons.

To fix the program change the type of marks to `int`:

```
int marks[10];
```

Note:
UB is invoked even on the first iteration because `"%d"` expects a pointer to `int` while type of `&marks[0]` is `char*`. This operation is undefined by C standard because `int*` and `char*` may differ in size and/or representation and/or alignment. However it is a unlikely case for modern CPUs.

Comment: ah m really stupid huh

Comment: @AkshatSharma You're not stupid — you made an easy mistake, and C can be a pretty unforgiving language.  Use a better compiler, if you can, or enable more warnings — a modern compiler would have warned you about this mistake right away.

Comment: "conjuring nasal deamons" I'm going to be extra careful with overflow checking from now on! :)

Answer (score 0):

You have declared the marks as a character array and tried to get input from user using %d which asks asks for an integer,

```
 #include <stdio.h>
int main(){

    int marks[10];
    int i;

    printf("enter the numbers:\n");
    printf("-------------------\n");
    
    for (i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",i);
        printf("element %d-",i);
        scanf("%d", &marks[i]);
    }

    printf("\n all %d",marks);
    printf("\n second %d\n",marks[1]);
return 0;
}
```

[image]

Also I didn't understand the use of all so I couldn't find a solution for it. If you want to print a specific number then you have to specify it like you have done it for second or if you want to display the total you want to add a furthermore code to calculate the sum of elements in the array.